# Unable to understand Regex behavior within CSharp

Tags: c#, regex

While working with the string I came across 2 string both containing 2(in nos) Commas **,**.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Regex rexCsvSplitter = new Regex(@",(?=(?:[^""]*""[^""]*"")*(?![^""]*""))");
        string str1 = "\"\"|\"FAN100\"|\"\"|\"XXXXX XXXXX,XXX.\"|\"9999 XXXXXX,XXX XXXXX\"|\"\"|\"XXXXXXXXXXX\"|\"ON\"|\"X9X 9X9\"|\"XXX\"|\"99\"|\"XXX\"|\"999 999-9999\"|\"999 999-9999\"|\"XXXX XXXX\"|\"xxx@xxx.xxx\"|\"N\"|\"\"|\"0099\"|\"XXX\"|\"X\"|\"\"|\"\"";
        string str2 = "\"\"|\"FAN100\"|\"\"|\"XXXXX XXXXX,XXX.\"|\"XX XXXX 9999,XXXXXX XXXXXX \"\"X\"\"|\"\"|\"XXXXXX\"|\"ON\"|\"XXX XXX\"|\"XXX\"|\"99\"|\"XXX\"|\"999 999-9999\"|\"999 999-9999\"|\"XXXX XXXX\"|\"xxx@xxx.xxx\"|\"N\"|\"\"|\"0099\"|\"XXX\"|\"X\"|\"\"|\"\"";
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World: {0}, {1}",rexCsvSplitter.Split(str1).Length,rexCsvSplitter.Split(str2).Length);
    }
}
```

In the above example both string `str1` and `str2` consist 2 commas but at different indexes. `,(?=(?:[^""]*""[^""]*"")*(?![^""]*""))` is splitting 'str1' with Length 1 and `str2` with Length 3.

Why is this happening, Can anyone explain ?

[Fiddle is here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CU8NRL)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is why people should use actual CSV parsers instead of using regex for the same thing; it gets confusing and hard to debug.

Comment: @Jerry I understand, just managing a legacy code :)

Comment: Use CSV parser like @Jerry said

Comment: https://regex101.com/ provides a nice way to visualise and debug regexes

Comment: `str2` has a column with unbalanced quotes `"XX XXXX 9999,XXXXXX XXXXXX ""X""` There should be one more quote at the end. The regex splits on commas with even number of quotes ahead. Because of this quote imbalance in `str2`, the split will be different.

Comment: I also find it strange that this code is splitting on commas while it looks like it should be splitting on pipes (`|`)...

Comment: Looks like you need to remove the double quotes and then split on the pip character : string[] array = str1.Replace("\"","").Split(new char[] { '|' });

Comment: @Jerry Your solution worked. Thanks !!